# Debugging code for a n-of command in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, percentage, agent-based-modeling

I've set up firms (turtles) in an industry (world) which either produce at home (firms-own: `reshored? false`) or have offshored their production (firms-own: `offshored? true`). Further, I have given them a `maximum-level-of-automation` and their current `level-of-automation`.

I have a monitor on my interface which defines the share of production tasks already automised which should be less than or equal to their `maximum-level-of-automation`:

```
breed [ firms firm ]

firms-own [
  offshored?   ;; true or false
  level-of-automation   ;; tbd
  max-level-of-automation   ;; randomly defined between 0 and 1
]

global [ 
  share-of-automated-firms   ;; in % in a slider on interface 
]

to go
  ask firms [ 
    set max-level-of-automation 0 + random-float 1 
    ifelse ( offshored? = false ) [
      ask n-of ( count firms * ( share-of-automated-firms / 100 ) ) firms [   
        set level-of-automation random-between ( 0.01 ) max-level-of-automation ] ] [  
      set level-of-automation 0 ] ]
end

to-report random-between [ min-num max-num ]
   report random-float (max-num - min-num) + min-num
end
```

I don't receive an error but the turtles also don't report it the way I want them to. I want only the particular `share-of-automated-firms` to change their `level-of-automation` to a number between zero and their `max-level-of-automation`. The rest should report zero.
I can´t find the error here. Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Your code here may be the issue:

```
ask firms [ 
    set max-level-of-automation 0 + random-float 1 
    ifelse ( offshored? = false ) [
      ask n-of ( count firms * ( share-of-automated-firms / 100 ) ) firms [   
        set level-of-automation random-between ( 0.01 ) max-level-of-automation ] ] [  
      set level-of-automation 0 ] ]
```

You have an `ask n-of ... firms` nested in an `ask firms` command block. Translated, that says "All firms, I want you to set your max automation to something. Then, if you're not offshored, I want you to either ask some number of firms to do something *or* set your own automation level to zero." So, every single firm is going to run that code and potentially ask some number of current firms to change their level of automation.

Comment: Aha I see. So you'd say that I would need to take my ```ask n-of ... firms``` out of the ``ask firms``` command block?

Comment: @user11277648 - Yes, that would probably help with this issue- it should be in a separate `ask` statement that is called once by the observer rather than potentially by all turtles.